# Control.Text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2012, controls

Currently I am in the process of converting one of my programs from WinForms to WPF. The first problem I have run into involves setting the text value of a control in WPF. In my WinForms program, I have working code that looks like this:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(Control c, string text);

private void SetText(Control c, string text)
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] {c, text});
    }
    else
    {
        c.Text = text; //This is where I have not found a way to replicate.
    }
}
```

I have changed a few things to get part to work, but so far, this is what I have in WPF that seems to work except for the part where I am actually trying to set the text of the control.

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(Control c, string text);

private void SetText(Control c, string text)
{
    if (c.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(d, new object[] {c, text});
    }
    else
    {
        c.Text = text;
    }
}
```

From what I have found out after reading things on this site and the MSDN sections is that I can call the c.Text command if the control was specifically a WPF textbox and then the c.Content command if the control was specifically a WPF label. However, I can't call either of these for a generic control c like I have here. Is there any method or command that I could use to set the Text value of my control c, or is there another way that I can modify the code so that I can still set up my SetText function that allows me to edit the text of any controls (textbox, label, etc.) in the same manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple different content models in WPF. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548.aspx) has a good primer on them.

Having said that, a cool thing you can do with a `DependencyProperty` is set it on an `DependencyObject` that may not care about it. You could therefore do:

```
c.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, text);
c.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, text);
```

This will cover most controls that display content.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 Sorry, I updated the answer with the correct static fields. I forgot to add the Property at the end. Both `ContentControl` and `TextBlock` are in `System.Windows.Controls`. I also was wrong that you can set `TextElement.TextProperty`, as `TextElement` only defines the text formatting properties, and not their content properties.

Comment: I have it now. I am not sure it if will work like I need it to, but at least it accepts it with no errors. I'll come back and mark it as the answer if it works.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 Something that I should point out is that since you're passing `Control`, you will never have a `TextBlock`, as it derives from `FrameworkElement`. You really may want to ask a question about what you're trying to accomplish, instead of your particular implementation details. There are some major differences between WPF and WinForms that should alter the way you approach problems.

Comment: I am starting to realize that as I am making the conversion. I think I might have found another totally different solution to the problem though. Thanks for helping me with this even though it really isn't the way I need to be going in the end.